# Support for a political figure without necessarily knowing/understanding or supporting their policies

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, politics

I know there is a word for this in Spanish but I can't remember what it is. I've been searching online for a while but have had no luck. All I remember is it's "C-something-ismo".

Is there an English word for this?

Comment: *Trumpian Politics*?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This site strives to provide well researched, intriguing questions. Kai, single word requests as yours are required to provide an example sentence about the way the word will be used. Take the [tour] or have a look at the [help] to find out more about good questions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word ***charisma*** but it is something which causes such support. 
ODO translates it to *[carisma](https://es.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/english-spanish/charisma)* in Spanish. I am not sure if there is a special word to denote that kind of support itself.

You may say, for example:

> The **charismatic** but incompetent leader beguiled the voters into
>   supporting him.

**ODO**:

> **[charisma](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charisma)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** [mass noun] Compelling attractiveness or charm that can inspire devotion in others.
>
> ‘he has tremendous charisma and stage presence’
>
> ‘I think he has charisma, but it's not the sort of charisma that
>   attracts the ordinary voter.’
>
> **[charismatic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charismatic)** *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** Exercising a compelling charm which inspires devotion in others. ‘he was a charismatic figure with great appeal to the public’
>
> ‘It was the charismatic crowd-pleaser who charmed the British public
>   and won two massive election victories for a Labour Party that had
>   almost given up hope of ever seeing power again.’